# Создать функцию возвращающую select

Tags: php, функции

Сделайте функцию, которая будет создавать селект. Функция должна
принимать многомерный массив такого типа:

```
`$arr = [
    ['value'=>'php', 'text'=>'Язык PHP'],
    ['value'=>'html', 'text'=>'Язык HTML'],
    ['value'=>'css', 'text'=>'Язык CSS'],
    ['value'=>'javascript', 'text'=>'Язык Javascript']
];`




function select($arr) {
    return  "<select>"
                foreach($arr as $elem) {
                    "<option value='$elem[value]'>$elem[text]</option>"
                }
            "</select>";
}

echo select($arr);
```

Я не пойму как совместить php и html.

Comment: Надо СНАЧАЛА получить нужные данные в переменную, и только потом их возвращать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно именно возвращать, то можно сделать вот так:

```
function select($arr) {
    $options = '';
    foreach($arr as $elem) {
        $options .= '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($elem["value"]).'">';
        $options .= htmlspecialchars($elem[text]).'</option>';
    }
    
    return  "<select>$options</select>";
}
```

Если нужно сразу вывести, то можно такой вариант:

```
function select($arr) {
    ?>
    <select>
        <?php foreach($arr as $elem) : ?>
            <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($elem["value"]) ?>">
                <?= htmlspecialchars($elem["text"]) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: странно, в $options .= используется экстраполяция, а s return - конкатенация. Лучше все-таки придерживаться единого стиля

Comment: Ну это на быструю руку набросл, можно подправить

Comment: Ну раз можно, то я поправил. Никогда не понимал стремление пхпшников писать как можно больше кавычек

Comment: ой и про безопасность я забыл